# Activerecord asociation not working on friend system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to test out a Facebook-style friend system. I have a simple User model and a UserRelationship model that takes two foreign keys from the users table, which I've named `inviter_id` and `invited_id`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_relationships
  has_many :friends, through: :user_relationships, source: :invited
end

class UserRelationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :invited, class_name: "User"
end
```

I've tried variations of this and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I want to be able to call `User.first.friends` and get a full friends list. currently the error I'm getting is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column user_relationships.user_id does not exist
```

The tables:

```
create_table "user_relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "inviter_id"
  t.integer  "invited_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Using what Abhilash said about the `has_many :user_relationships` association I changed it to this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_relationships, foreign_key: "invited_id"
  has_many :friends, through: :user_relationships, source: :invited
end
```

The problem is that that only returns the inviteds, not the inviters. I feel like there should be a way to get both using the database and associations?

Comment: Can you please post the table structure of user_relationships

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I added the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the below line from the `User` model.

```
has_many :user_relationships
```

Because in the `UserRelationship` model you've fields for `inviter_id` and `invited_id` but not `user_id`.

So you can have a method like this in your model to get `user_relationships` for a given user.

```
def user_relationships
    UserRelationship.where("invited_id = ? OR inviter_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

Edited:

You can also have associations like below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inviter_user_relationships, :class_name => 'UserRelationship', :foreign_key => 'inviter_id'
  has_many :invited_user_relationships, :class_name => 'UserRelationship', :foreign_key => 'invited_id'

  def user_relationships
    inviter_user_relationships + invited_user_relationships
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does work, but also it feels as though you should be able to do it using the database and associations. Do you have any idea how that might work?

Comment: Updated the answer. But I think there is no direct way to have more than one foreign key for an association.

Comment: Yeah I've had a look around and I think you're right. Thanks for your help.